# CSS: Select the last child from last row?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make a simple highlight when a user hovers the last date in the range date picker. I'm using a lib so I can't really change the inside things, but before I want to try to achieve this with pure CSS instead of jQuery. Maybe I'm just missing something. So the thing is that when user hovers a date it adds `datepicker__month-day--hovering` class and the `:last-child and :last-of-type` selectors selects all the last elements in the rows that they exists, but not the one that I'm currently hovering, how can I fix it?

This is my structure:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="datepicker__week-row">
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1672524000000" d="1" role="button" index="1" aria-label="Not available, Sunday, January 01, 2023" aria-disabled="true">1</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1672610400000" d="2" role="button" index="2" aria-label="Not available, Monday, January 02, 2023" aria-disabled="true">2</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1672696800000" d="3" role="button" index="3" aria-label="Not available, Tuesday, January 03, 2023" aria-disabled="true">3</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1672783200000" d="4" role="button" index="4" aria-label="Not available, Wednesday, January 04, 2023" aria-disabled="true">4</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1672869600000" d="5" role="button" index="5" aria-label="Not available, Thursday, January 05, 2023" aria-disabled="true">5</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1672956000000" d="6" role="button" index="6" aria-label="Not available, Friday, January 06, 2023" aria-disabled="true">6</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673042400000" d="7" role="button" index="7" aria-label="Not available, Saturday, January 07, 2023" aria-disabled="true">7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="datepicker__week-row">
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673128800000" d="1" role="button" index="8" aria-label="Not available, Sunday, January 08, 2023" aria-disabled="true">8</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673215200000" d="2" role="button" index="9" aria-label="Not available, Monday, January 09, 2023" aria-disabled="true">9</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673301600000" d="3" role="button" index="10" aria-label="Not available, Tuesday, January 10, 2023" aria-disabled="true">10</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673388000000" d="4" role="button" index="11" aria-label="Not available, Wednesday, January 11, 2023" aria-disabled="true">11</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673474400000" d="5" role="button" index="12" aria-label="Not available, Thursday, January 12, 2023" aria-disabled="true">12</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673560800000" d="6" role="button" index="13" aria-label="Not available, Friday, January 13, 2023" aria-disabled="true">13</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673647200000" d="7" role="button" index="14" aria-label="Not available, Saturday, January 14, 2023" aria-disabled="true">14</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="datepicker__week-row">
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673733600000" d="1" role="button" index="15" aria-label="Not available, Sunday, January 15, 2023" aria-disabled="true">15</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673820000000" d="2" role="button" index="16" aria-label="Not available, Monday, January 16, 2023" aria-disabled="true">16</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid        " daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673906400000" d="3" role="button" index="17" aria-label="Not available, Tuesday, January 17, 2023" aria-disabled="true">17</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--today    datepicker__month-day--checkin-only    datepicker__month-day--first-day-selected  datepicker__month-day--selected  datepicker__month-day--tmp" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1673992800000" d="4" role="button" tabindex="0" index="18" aria-label="Selected as check-in date, Wednesday, January 18, 2023" aria-disabled="false">18</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid datepicker__month-day--tmp  datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674079200000" d="5" role="button" index="19" aria-label="Not available, Thursday, January 19, 2023" aria-disabled="true">19</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid datepicker__month-day--tmp  datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674165600000" d="6" role="button" index="20" aria-label="Not available, Friday, January 20, 2023" aria-disabled="true">20</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid datepicker__month-day--tmp  datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674252000000" d="7" role="button" index="21" aria-label="Not available, Saturday, January 21, 2023" aria-disabled="true">21</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="datepicker__week-row">
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--invalid datepicker__month-day--tmp  datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674338400000" d="1" role="button" index="22" aria-label="Not available, Sunday, January 22, 2023" aria-disabled="true">22</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp  datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674424800000" d="2" role="button" index="23" aria-label="Choose Monday, January 23, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">23</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp  datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674511200000" d="3" role="button" index="24" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, January 24, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">24</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp  datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674597600000" d="4" role="button" index="25" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, January 25, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">25</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp datepicker__month-day--hovering" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674684000000" d="5" role="button" index="26" aria-label="Choose Thursday, January 26, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">26</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674770400000" d="6" role="button" index="27" aria-label="Choose Friday, January 27, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">27</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674856800000" d="7" role="button" index="28" aria-label="Choose Saturday, January 28, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">28</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="datepicker__week-row">
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1674943200000" d="1" role="button" index="29" aria-label="Choose Sunday, January 29, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">29</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1675029600000" d="2" role="button" index="30" aria-label="Choose Monday, January 30, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">30</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--visibleMonth datepicker__month-day--valid datepicker__month-day--tmp" daytype="visibleMonth" time="1675116000000" d="3" role="button" index="31" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, January 31, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">31</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--nextMonth datepicker__month-day--valid        " daytype="nextMonth" time="1675202400000" d="4" role="button" index="0" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, February 01, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">1</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--nextMonth datepicker__month-day--valid        " daytype="nextMonth" time="1675288800000" d="5" role="button" index="0" aria-label="Choose Thursday, February 02, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">2</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--nextMonth datepicker__month-day--valid        " daytype="nextMonth" time="1675375200000" d="6" role="button" index="0" aria-label="Choose Friday, February 03, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">3</td>
      <td class="datepicker__month-day datepicker__month-day--nextMonth datepicker__month-day--valid        " daytype="nextMonth" time="1675461600000" d="7" role="button" index="0" aria-label="Choose Saturday, February 04, 2023 as your check-out date" aria-disabled="false">4</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot (obviously) add a class using CSS. What you can do instead is to use the `:hover` pseudo-class. Have you tried it? Said that, you cannot persist a *"selected"* state by just using `:hover`. JavaScript might be a better solution - but again it depends on your task - which I still cannot reason about the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: hey, I do not need to add any classes, the lib does it itself, I just need to find a way how to properly select those elements with these given classes. The issue is that with my selector it selects all the last elements in the row (calendar) but not the actual last element with that class (datepicker__month-day--hovering)